# rust: using hashmap arc and rwlock across multiple threads

Tags: rust

Trying to wrap my head around how to insert things to a hasmap from different threads, but still couldn't get it.

Why is the following program on every execution missing some keys?
My current understanding is that `.write` wait to acquire the lock and `.join` wait for all threads to finish?

Thus I would expect to eventually all threads to insert their values into the hashmap, but obviously I am still missing something.

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ac936ffc8aa39ae4176492fb712ae69b)

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::RwLock;
use std::thread;
use std::vec;

pub fn main() {
    let mut contacts: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    contacts.insert("main-thread".to_owned(), "hello world".to_owned());

    let contacts = Arc::new(RwLock::new(contacts));
    let mut children = vec![];
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let lock_contacts = Arc::clone(&contacts);
        children.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            let num = thread::current().id();
            let num = format!("{num:?}");
            if let Ok(mut contacts) = lock_contacts.write() {
                contacts.insert(num.clone(), "hey".to_owned());
            }
        }));
    }
    let _ = children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join());
    dbg!(contacts);
}
```

Comment: Don't _silence_ warnings without _reading and understanding_ them first (`warning: unused `Map` that must be used`).

Comment: I am not aware of having them silenced, probably doing something foolish without knowing, what did I do I can't see?

Comment: `let _ = `. Didn't you add that because of the warning?

Comment: Not consciously at least, I added that because I didn't care about the result and wrongly assumed what the compiler wanted to tell me and moved on too fast. Now I see your point, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not actually joining threads before exiting from the main. And your culprit is this line.

```rust
let _ = children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join());
```

This line **does nothing**. There is no iteration, and that is because iterators in rust are *lazy*. If you would not discard value returned from the map, you would get a following warning.

```
warning: unused `Map` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:23:5
   |
23 |     children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join());
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed
   = note: `#[warn(unused_must_use)]` on by default
help: use `let _ = ...` to ignore the resulting value
   |
23 |     let _ = children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join());
   |     +++++++
```

Note this part: **iterators are lazy and do nothing unless consumed**.

The solution is not to ignore this warning, but to instead iterate over the values and actually join threads. You can do it either by using a consuming iterator-adaptor like [Iterator::for_each](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.for_each):

```rust
children.into_iter().for_each(|c| c.join().unwrap());
```

or simply using a `for` loop:

```rust
for child in children {
    child.join().unwrap()
}
```

Comment: You could also `collect()` (with some explicit type-specs) in order to retrieve any panic from one of the threads, that'll run the iterator.

Answer (score 3):

Your mistake was in this line:

```rust
let _ = children.into_iter().map(|c| c.join());
```

Recall from the Rust book that [iterators are lazy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html#processing-a-series-of-items-with-iterators). `Iterator::map` merely creates an adapter, but does not actually evaluate the values. Therefore your code is not actually synchronized.

To fix this, you can either:

1. evaluate the iterator, probably using [`Iterator::collect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect);
2. or use a simple `for` loop instead.